# How can I make all posible combinations from a list of booleans in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to create a function where, given 6 booleans, I would return all posibles combinations.

So, for example one posible combination would be:

- bool_1 = True
- bool_2 = True
- bool_3 = True
- bool_4 = True
- bool_5 = True
- bool_6 = True

And a second combination would be:

- bool_1 = True
- bool_2 = True
- bool_3 = True
- bool_4 = True
- bool_5 = True
- bool_6 = False

Is this possible?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Comment: please look at [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) this is basic permutation problem

Comment: This looks a lot like counting in binary to me. If you're comfortable with how it works, it should not be too hard to create a function like `getCombination(i)` which gives you the i-th combination

Comment: `for item in itertools.product([True,False], repeat=6):`

Comment: I suggest creating generator which will loop through `range(63,-1,-1)` and yield for each element value `list(map(bool, bin(x)[2:]))`. It will return exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With recursion:** 
An approach without using libraries.

**Code:**

```
ans=[]
def TF(n,l):
    global ans
    if(n==0):
        ans.append(l)
        return l
    l.append(True)
    TF(n-1,l[:])
    l.pop()
    l.append(False)
    TF(n-1,l[:])

l=[]
TF(3,l)
print(ans)
```

**Output:**

```
[[True, True, True], [True, True, False], [True, False, True], [True, False, False], [False, True, True], [False, True, False], [False, False, True], [False, False, False]]
```

For 6 booleans, execute TF(6,l)